# How to display Hindi Fonts in a pdf which is generated from Jsp page?

Tags: jsp, pdf, hindi

In my project I have Report Module in which we need to generate pdf File for the dynamic data fetched from database . I can able to show it in English . But I also should display the same content in Hindi Language .In the grid ( jsp page ) it is coming in Hindi , but in pdf , i am not able to generate it. Please provide me some answer , Expecting Ur repliles

this is how I am generating pdf from Jsp Page :  It is printing in pdf in English but i need to print the same in Hindi . These following

```
    <display:column property="strTemp" title="Travel Time[hh:mm] "></display:column>
    <display:column property="strDuration" title="Halt Time[hh:mm]"></display:column>
    <display:column property="dblcumulativedist" format="{0,number,0.00}" title="Total Travel Distance [km]" ></display:column>
    <display:column property="assigned" title="Job Assigned"></display:column>
    <display:column property="completed" title="Job Completed"></display:column>
    <display:column property="pending" title="Job Pending"></display:column>
```

Comment: how are you generating PDF ? In PDF, what is printed for hindi text ?

Comment: please be more specific on how you generate the PDF if you want any answers - my first guess would be that you didn't install the Hindi font on your server that's used by the pdf generator, but like I said - be specific